# Scala reflection. How to get child field value from parent?

Tags: scala

I have a parent class:

```
     abstract case class Model[T] (id: Option[String]) {
      protected val FIELDS : List[String]
```

and number of children of it.
I'm trying to get values of children classes using Reflection like this:

```
        val m = ru.runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
        for (field <- this.FIELDS) {
          val term = ru.typeOf[Model[T]].decl(ru.TermName(field)).asTerm
          val im = m.reflect(this)
          val fieldMirror = im.reflectField(term)
          Logger.debug(fieldMirror.get.toString)
        }
```

I've got compiler error

> No TypeTag available for models.Model[T]

If insted of Model[T] i put name of actual child class everything works. But I need this code to be generic. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class itself must hold the `TypeTag`:

```
abstract case class Model[T: ru.TypeTag] (id: Option[String])
```

Comment: It seems like correct answer but now I've got Exception: <none> is not a term at runtime.